# Logitech m150 wireless mouse is behaving totally reverse in Ubuntu 19.04 update. Please help

Tags: updates, mouse, 19.04, logitech, reverse-tethering

I updated from 18.04 to 18.10 and then to 19.04. the mouse and trackpad are behaving totally in reverse direction. Can it be solved?

Comment: Try disabling "natural scrolling" in track/touchpad settings.